# Configure directory so that each new file has always same group ownership

Tags: permissions, directory

I have the following directory

```
$ ls -al
total 16
drwxr-xr-x  4 root  root    4096 Oct 21 14:50 .
drwxr-xr-x 24 root  root    4096 Oct 21 11:28 ..
drwxrwx---  8 root mygroup 4096 Jan 12  2022 foobar
```

Is there a way to configure `foobar`'s permissions, so that each new file created belongs by default to `mygroup` group?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting the `setgid` bit for a directory should do precisely what you're after (assuming your Unix-like OS and/or filesystem supports it):

```
chmod g+s foobar
```

After that, the permissions should look like:

```
drwxrws---  8 root mygroup 4096 Jan 12  2022 foobar
```

If I remember my Unix history correctly, the BSD branch of the Unix family tree used to set the group owner of any new files based on the group of the directory the file was created in by default. On the other hand, the SystemV-based branch set the group ownership based on the primary group of the process creating the file.

In the strict old SysV style, the commands `sg` and `newgrp` would have been important tools when users were working with group projects. But then SunOS 4.x and System V Release 4 allowed the system administrator to use the setgid bit on directories to choose whether the BSD or classic SysV group ownership assignment style was in effect in that directory.

This "setgid on directories" behavior was adopted by several OSs of the Unix family, including Linux. But I think there are OSs that didn't adopt it (maybe in the BSD side, as the SysV branch's "optional behavior" was already their standard behavior?). And the choice of filesystem type might also affect whether this feature is available or not.